# drop rows based on a condition based on another

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame

| user_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 1 | 15 |
| 1 | 35 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 2 | 14 |

I want to drop all rows that are not the maximum value of every user_id

resulting on a 2 row data frame:

| user_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 35 |
| 2 | 14 |

How can I do that?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.max`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) after the grouping.
Assuming that your original dataframe is named `df`, try the code below :

```
out = df.groupby('user_id', as_index=False).max('value')
```

##### `>>> print(out)`

[image]

##### Edit :

If you want to group more than one column, use this :

```
out = df.groupby(['user_id', 'sex'], as_index=False, sort=False)['value'].max()
```

#### `>>> print(out)`

[image]

Comment: `df.groupby('user_id').max('value')` ?

Comment: thank you, if I have a couple more columns, how do I so they dont get dropped out of the result?

Comment: I added an EDIT in the end of my answer, check it out !

Comment: @EnriqueMartin `nlargest` method can be helpful in your case: `df.groupby('user_id').apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1, 'value'))`

Comment: Thank you everyone. L'Artiste your solution will not work because grouping by user_id and sex will return many rows for a user_id as many combinations of those 2 variables exists. Boris your solution works perfectly did not know nlargest function, thank you very much!